# What are the differences between ThroughputConnectionFactory, ConnectionFactory, XAConnectionFactory and XAConnectionThroughputConnectionFactory

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I am looking at using HornetQ as the Messaging Provider. I'd like to know what connection factory is suitable for what behavior/solution?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation ? XA<name> is for "global" transaction, accessing more than one data store. So if I were you I would check documentation and the improve question to include what you want to use the queue for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connectionfactory is the base one. Specifically, `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` is the java interface for JMS connection factories.

As it says in the documentation, [HornetQ User Guide, Performance Tuning](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.beta2/docs/user-manual/html_single/index.html#perf-tuning), you could use the pre configured ThroughputConnectionFactory for a tuned in CF for heavy load of small messages.

The XA ones are just prepared for global transactions through JTA when running inside JBoss AS. So you should go for these if you use multi resource transactions (such as Queue <-> DB transactions).